# Redirect specific URLs to 404 with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a list of 3 links I want to refer to the 404 error page.

- `https://example.com/a/`
- `https://example.com/b/`
- `https://example.com/c/`

Is there a way to write in the `.htaccess` file that anyone who enters these links will be redirected to error 404 ?

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^a [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^b [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^c [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read about `ErrorDocument` property of htaccess, it should be an easy find on SO, cheers.

Comment: it is not work :/

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^a [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^b [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^c [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

Comment: Good that you are showing your efforts, keep it up. Please post them in your question comments are not meant for codes, kindly add them with CODE TAGS on your question.

Comment: tnx i edit my post

Comment: So irrespective of either file is present on system or not you want to give error `404`? Or is it like you want to forbid access on matched urls? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: If you had read [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) carefully, you would know that `%{THE_REQUEST}` contains _“the full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "`GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`")”_ That a regex like `^a`, anchored at the start, will never match this, should be pretty obvious.

Comment: I want anyone who go into https://somename.com/a/ to get error 404. If he go to https://somename.com/d/ it's fine.

Comment: _“I want anyone who go into somename.com/a to get error 404”_ - and why would that not happen automatically in the first place? Unless a file or folder by that name actually exists, that should be the default behaviour to begin with. So if that doesn’t happen, then there must be more stuff in play here, that you neglected to tell us about so far.

Comment: Because there really is such a link. But I wish they did not know about him. Hacked into my store and put in gambling links and I want to avoid those links. Google's index is flooded with gambling and that's a problem. I'm looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have other directives then you can do this with a single `RedirectMatch` directive. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/(a|b|c)/$
```

Any request URL that matches *exactly* `/a/`, `/b/` or `/c/` (as in your example) will be sent to your 404 error document.

However, if you have existing mod_rewrite directives then it may be preferable to use mod_rewrite instead, to avoid potential conflicts (and general efficiency). For example, the following would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)/$ - [R=404]
```

No need for the `L` flag when using a non-3xx code with the `R` flag, since it is implied. Note there is no slash prefix with the `RewriteRule` directive, as there is with `RedirectMatch`.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^a [NC]
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^b [NC]
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^c [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
> ```

This doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `THE_REQUEST` doesn't only contain the requested URL, it contains the first line of the HTTP request header. eg. `GET /a/ HTTP/1.1` - so a regex of the form `^a` will never match.
2. All the conditions (`RewriteCond` directives) are AND'd by default, so it could never be `a` AND `b` AND `C`. You would need to use the `OR` flag on the first two conditions to create a logical *OR*.